# Как оптимальнее передавать данные MS Word API?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Задача: поместить диалоги VK в документ MS Word.

Макет с заказчиком сделали. Но когда я начал впихивать данные — оказалось, что для моих 65к сообщений (я не особо общительный, аккаунту 3 года) потребуется от 2 до 8 часов. При этом возможны потери данных при подвисании компьютера.

Я создаю параграфы и наполняю их данными (по очереди, для каждого сообщения). Насколько я понимаю, потоки в этом деле не помогут, т.к. простоя не много. 
Может быть стоит создавать шаблон для диалога, а после давать данные? Мне почему-то кажется, что это будет ещё медленнее.

Что посоветуете?

**UPD**
Сам же и ввел путаницу.
Сообщения я уже скачал. Сформировал всё в JSON-объект, сериализовал в строку и сохранил в текстовик. Теперь нужно данные из текстовика сунуть в документ MS Word (с форматированием и блекджеком). Вот тут то и проблема: Word API работает крайне медленно.

Я беру сообщение из текстовика, и сую его с нужным форматированием в MS Word. Это занимает 0.1 — 0.5 секунды. При 65к сообщений это от 2 до 8 часов, что недопустимо много.

Может быть кто-нибудь подскажет, какая логика будет шустрее отрабатывать?

Comment: А где простой-то? Чтение из ВК? Запись в документ?

Comment: Нету простоя. Я спрашиваю как сделать быстрее(какая логика будет быстрее), а не где мне убрать простой, который я не ставил.
PS Либо я вас не понял, либо вы не внимательно прочли вопрос.

Comment: Я выразился некорректно. Где затык? На получении данных из ВК или при записи в водровский документ через интероп?

Comment: интероп. Дополнил вопрос, что бы развеять непонятки.

Comment: а как с вашим вопросом связаны метки `auth` и `qiwi`?

Comment: эммм, не знаю, извиняюсь) Я тут новенький)

Answer (score 1):

Быстрее Word Interop - использовать библиотеку для генерации `.docx` файлов. Можно использовать как OpenXML, так и какую-нибудь другую, например [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/), [Netoffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) и т.п. Минус OpenXML в сложности API. Другие библиотеки попроще. Советую посмотреть сразу на NPOI.

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо!

Comment: Просматриваю NPOI, но кроме работы с excel ничего не вижу. Excel тоже нежен, но для начала нужен ворд...

Comment: Netoffice так же запускает приложение(судя по примеру для c#).

Comment: Решил свою проблему использованием библиотеки DocX. Всем советую. Скорость супер.